# Zend framework 1.2 handling 404

Tags: zend-framework, dynamic, routes, http-status-code-404

I am having one requirement that I want to manage 404 error differently.

When a system found 404, so before moving it to errorController, it should first check in a table which saves data for special urls and internal project url, if an entry found then it should internally execute that internal url and show the output on the page without changing url.

If no entry found in the table then it should move to error controller as it is.

Please help me on this, I have tried and succeeded using dynamic routing from db, but it is pushing route entries each time page initialize and I want to check this only on 404 to avoid useless load on system.

Thanks

Comment: IMHO this is bad practice. 404s are for 404s, they shouldn't be used as a poor man's catch-all route. If you had dynamic routing from the DB working, worst-case this would be one additional DB query per request. What performance issue was this causing you?

Comment: It is uselessly adding routing to the system at each instance. Which I actually required only when 404 raised from the main system. Or if it is possible that if system not able to find the requested url then it should go to check for this routing. Just want to add dynamic routing only when it required.

Comment: Does your dynamic routing add one route per special URL (which would be bad)? Could you add the relevant code for it to your question?

Comment: Currently I am pushing routing like this, it works fine. But I would like to have this only when other routers are failed or system is not able to find controller and action for the given url. The reason is that I may have 100-200 different records in this particular table.
<pre> <code>
$stmt = $db->query("select * from pages");
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
       $router->addRoute('dynamicRoute'.$row->id, new Zend_Controller_Router_Route($row->accessUrl . "/*", array('controller' => $row->internalController, 'action' => $row->internalAction)));
    }
</code></pre>

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to do a route per URL, that will be slow. You can do it with a single route if you use a custom route class. Take a look at http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework - whilst that solves a different problem the approach should work for you.